# Getting AppEngine AppAssertionCredentials working (Python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-admin-sdk

I am updating an App Engine python project from the old Google Admin SDK API to the new one and having difficulty getting the [built in services account](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine#ServiceAccounts) ([AppAssertionCredentials](http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.appengine.AppAssertionCredentials-class.html))authenticated.

I have already

- Enabled the Admin SDK API in the Developers console
- Enabled API access in the Google Apps dashboard

To work around this I created a service account from the Developers console, downloaded the credentials.json, and set the following permissions (without quotes) in the Google Apps dashboard (Security > Advanced settings > Manage API client access) for that account:

- client: "{ service account id }.apps.googleusercontent.com"
- permissions:  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly"

My current code is (redacted slightly)

```
# ...

import json
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

GAPPS_CREDENTIALS = 'credentials.json'
GAPPS_SCOPES = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly'
]
GAPPS_ADMIN = 'admin'
GAPPS_DOMAIN = 'domain.com'
GAPPS_USER = 'user'

# ...

with open(GAPPS_CREDENTIALS) as jsonfile:
  jsondata = json.load(jsonfile)
  credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    jsondata['client_email'],
    jsondata['private_key'],
    scope=GAPPS_SCOPES,
    sub=GAPPS_ADMIN+'@'+GAPPS_DOMAIN
)

http = credentials.authorize(Http(memcache))
apps = build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http)
user = apps.users().get(userKey=GAPPS_USER +'@'+GAPPS_DOMAIN ).execute()
console.log(user['email'])

# ...
```

This works perfectly, however if I can, I would like to eliminate the credentials.json file by using a `AppAssertionCredentials` call to authenticate.

As soon as I run the following code,  however:

```
# ...

import json
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials

GAPPS_CREDENTIALS = 'credentials.json'
GAPPS_SCOPES = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly'
]
GAPPS_ADMIN = 'admin'
GAPPS_DOMAIN = 'domain.com'
GAPPS_USER = 'user'

# ...

credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope=GAPPS_SCOPES,sub=GAPPS_ADMIN+'@'+GAPPS_DOMAIN)
http = credentials.authorize(Http(memcache))
apps = build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http)
user = apps.users().get(userKey=GAPPS_USER +'@'+GAPPS_DOMAIN ).execute()
console.log(user['email'])

# ...
```

I get a 403 error:

```
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/user%domain.com?alt=json returned "Not Authorized to access this resource/api">
```

I suspect the issue may be that the built-in service account is not authenticated in Google Apps Dashboard,  however I am unable to find the account domain either in the Developers Console or the App Engine Console to be able to add these permissions. I have tried:

- adding all the service accounts found under Developers Console > Permissions, changing @developer.gserviceaccount.com to .apps.googleusercontent.com (the @cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com account causes error: `This client name has not been registered with Google yet.`)
- using the {project}.appspot.com domain: Google Apps errors with `This client name has not been registered with Google yet.`

Can anyone shed any light?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever happen to find a solution to this? I find myself in the same boat - can use offline secrets file to do it, but no matter how many times I browser through https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount and related links I can't find a client name that works for the default service account.

Comment: Unfortunately not, had to stick with using the credentials.json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question about where to find the email address form of the App Engine default service account: This is located in the new console under Permissions -> Service Accounts (as opposed to API Manager -> Credentials for service accounts you create yourself).

Now to answer the main question: AppAssertionCredentials won't work for Service Accounts with delegated access, as it [does not accept a 'sub' parameter](http://oauth2client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/source/oauth2client.contrib.appengine.html) for the constructor and [doesn't have a method for creating delegated credentials](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/contrib/appengine.py#L137) (it's not used as a keyword argument as with SignedJwtAssertionCredentials, which is now [ServiceAccountCredentials](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/service_account.py#L47), and is ignored). You should still be able to use the App Engine default service account with delegation though, since the new console now allows you to [create JSON keys for the default service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#howtheywork).

It's potentially possible to support delegated access with AppAssertionCredentials, and for this you could post a feature request on the [project issue tracker](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/issues).